# React-redux best way to select item from list

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm writing a react-redux app composed mostly of a list of projects. There are two main components, one displaying all the projects, `ProjectListing`, and one for displaying a selected project, `Project`. I want the `Project` component to be tied to a route, so I'm also using react-router. I have the routes set up like this:

```js
<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={ProjectListing} />
    <Route path="/project/:projectId" component={Project} />
  </Route> 
</Router>
```

The layout of the redux store looks like this:

```js
{
  projects: [
    {
      id: <some-uuid>,
      imageUrl: '/image.png',
    },
    {
      id: <other-uuid>,
      imageUrl: '/other-image.png',
    }
  ],
  selectedProject: <some-uuid>, // null signifies no selected project
}
```

Inside of `App`'s `componentWillMount`, I dispatch an action, `fetchProjects`, that fetches the list of projects from the server and puts them in the store.

Inside of `Project`'s `componentWillMount`, I dispatch an action, `selectProject`, that sets the current projectId to the one from the route, and does some additional client side processing of the image stored in the project.

The problem I'm having is that the two actions are dispatched at the same time, and `selectProject` is failing because `fetchProjects` hasn't been completed yet, and there are no projects in the store.

I read somewhere that it's better to keep less data within the store, which is why I'm only using the projectId to pull the selected project from the list of projects, instead of fetching the individual project within the `Project` component and having the `selectedProject` field be a copy of the project.

Is there any way to make the two actions dispatch in order, so that the projects are within the store when `selectProject` is disptached? I can't have `fetchProjects` also dispatch `selectProject` because `ProjectListing` doesn't have a selected project yet. Would it make more sense to fetch the one project inside the `Project` component instead of relying on all the projects already being in the store? I'm still fairly new to react-redux, so I'm not aware of the best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on your decision to fetch all the projects once, I see two options:

- Keep a `isLoading` flag to indicate whether data is still fetching. Map this flag to `Project` in `mapStateToProps`, then use `componentWillRecieveProps` to conditionally select the project when the data is ready (`if (!nextProps.isLoading && nextProps.projects) { ... }`).
  *Note: be careful about the condition you're using, you only want to select the project once when `projectId` changes and when the data is ready.*
- If the list of projects is only relevant in those two routes and not anywhere else in your app, you can fetch the data either in `ProjectListing` or `Project` (instead of in `App`), whichever of them mounts first.

  In that case, you can use a single action creator which will optionally select a specific project once the data is fetched successfully (`fetchProjects(projectIdToSelect)` or something similar).